# ORM/Doctrine2 - When to persist?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

This has been bugging me for a while.
In Doctrine2, we have the:  `ObjectManager` function:

```
void persist(object $object = null)
```

You only need to call it on new entities.

My question though, is "when" should it be called?  Immediately after creating the entity, or immediately before flushing it?

I can't find any documentation indicating the convention.  The reason this is important is because Doctrine dispatches the "persist event" when calling.

Given that the object might still be empty, it seems to imply that any functionality tagged on to that event should disregard the importance of the data the object contains at that point in time.

Am I correct in that statement or is there a convention Doctrine promotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create your new object, use it anyway you want, and when you're done with it and want to send it to your database, then persist it, just before flushing it.

If you persisted your entity just after creating it, any changes you would make wouldn't be taken into account when sent to the database.

Comment: This actually falls in line with my philosophy that objects should be flushed only at the very end of execution. But another issue presented by this answer which may contradict my own approach are the objects created by services.  I have experimented with the idea that objects should be persisted only by the top layer of code, similar to C where the procedure that requested memory is solely responsible for freeing it.  Does this also make sense to you?

Comment: I don't feel objects have to be persisted from the top layer of the code, you can create services that create and persist objects. The book (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) gives the example of a service for persisting objects, so I guess it is not a bad thing to do. You just use a service-oriented architecture.